# How to enable k8s to log label data in the log

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

Is there a way to let docker/kubelet to log the labels of a pod in the log?
What is the configuration?

For now, we can only get the labels of a running pod, if a pod is gone, you cannot use kubectl/docker describe to get the metadata of a pod.

I am trying to get the metadata especially the labels of a pod that already diminished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found the answer by myself.

There is no direct way to log the metadata for a pod in the log.
Based on the documents in K8s, there are 2 ways

1. Expose the metadata using environment variables and print the env out. See this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/)
2. Expose the metadata using dowanward volume api. You can expose the metadata to a volume and then read it from there. See this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/)